# Calling server.inject() POST request not calling handler in Hapi.js

Tags: testing, hapi.js

I have a Jasmine test spec test_spec.js like this:

```
describe('my tests', () => {
  it('POST should return 201 created', () => {
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/v1.0/message',
      payload: JSON.stringify({name: 'Ethan'})
    };
    server.inject(req, res => {
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(201);
    });
  });
});
```

The route for the API call looks like this:

```
var routes = [{
  path: '/api/v1.0/message',
  method: 'POST',
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    reply('Success').created();
  }
}];
exports.register = function(server, options, next) {
  server.route(routes);
  next();
}
```

When I run the tests, though, this particular test's `expect()` function doesn't get called because the `server.inject()` method doesn't call the response callback. In fact, not even the route handler method gets called (I checked with console.log statements). However, when I change the request method and the route from POST to GET, it works and the test calls the `expect()` method as expected. The test just doesn't work with POST requests. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you make a full runnable example of this (extract it from your app if it's big) rather than snippets?

Comment: I combined the route definition and route handler to simplify the code. If I were to paste the Hapi boilerplate code here as well, it would make it clunky with. To replicate this, one basically just takes a Hapi boilerplate and inserts the above route + handler. Then writes the above Jasmine test and executes via `jasmine` command in terminal.

Comment: I disagree. If you provide a minimal working example that we can run, it makes it easier to help. I can't do much with the above because it looks fine. Your problem probably lies outside of what you've supplied.

Comment: You're correct. I spent the time to generate the absolute minimum example and it worked there, so this must be tied to something else in the code. Very strange. I will report here when I find out what it was in case it was something that could help others. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was in the test call `describe()` snippet posted in my question. I neglected to call the `done()` function inside the `server.inject()` call. Once I added that, the POST test started getting called:

```
describe('my tests', () => {
  it('POST should return 201 created', (done) => {
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/v1.0/message',
      payload: JSON.stringify({name: 'Ethan'})
    };
    server.inject(req, res => {
      expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(201);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

The need to call the `done()` callback wasn't obvious to me from the Jasmine documentation. The call is necessary in order to postpone the spec completion until `done()` is called (meaning payload is posted).

Comment: I would always use "return reply" when calling the response callback